# History of Laplacian comparison theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ho.history-overview

The Laplacian comparison theorem says that if a $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold has nonnegative Ricci curvature, then the distance function to any point satisfies $\Delta d\leq\frac{n-1}{d}$. There is also a Hessian comparison theorem, and versions for different curvature bounds.

These are covered in several books on differential geometry, but I haven't been able to find any information on their history. Where were they first established?

Comment: It seems this goes back to  Calabi's "An extension of E. Hopf’s maximum principle with an application to Riemannian geometry". Duke Math. J., 25:45–56, 1958. See https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-25/issue-1/An-extension-of-E-Hopfs-maximum-principle-with-an-application/10.1215/S0012-7094-58-02505-5.full.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great paper. I see there's also an extension of the usual Hopf-Rinow theorem. Although that does answer the version of the theorem I put in my question, I am still curious about the more general version.

Comment: Modern history can be traced from the references on p.1 of Eschenburg's "Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry", see http://www.math.toronto.edu/~vtk/eschenburg-comparison.pdf. I think the subject originates from ODE comparison theorems, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_theorem. For example, Sturm's comparison theorem is in J. Math. Pures Appl. 1 (1836), 106–186.

Comment: Using Sturm for Jacobi fields is perhaps due to Toponogov? As for volume comparison, when did Bishop prove his inequality?

Comment: @DeaneYang: the usual proof of the Jacobi field comparison theorem (which I think is due to Rauch) reduces to the Sturm comparison theorem. This is explained in many places, e.g. Lee's "Riemannian geometry". This is how one shows that e.g. an upper sectional curvature bound gives a lower bound on the conjugate radius. Toponogov's theorem is more involved.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, I forgot about Rauch. To my surprise, few people cite Rauch's original paper. It appears to be this one: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969309

Comment: @DeaneYang Bishop announced his work in the 1963 Notices of the AMS